# PostgreSQL Revoking Permissions from pg_catalog tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Is there a way I can revoke permissions from a user to the catalog objects (i.e. information_schema) and PostgreSQL tables (i.e. pg_catalog)? I've tried several things and scoured the net. I'm not having any luck. The only thing I read that is partially helpful is I may not want to remove "public" from the system tables in case user defined functions rely on an object in one of those schemas. The commands below are a small snap shot of what I have not gotten to work with the exception of a single table.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM PUBLIC; -- didn't work
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM public; -- didn't work
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM user1; -- didn't work
REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_roles FROM user1; -- worked
REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_database FROM user1;  -- didn't work

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM g_users; -- didn't work
REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_database FROM g_users;  -- didn't work
```

Any ideas? Or is this just not possible? Thanks...

Leslie

Comment: Define "didn't work". Also, what's your PostgreSQL version? `SELECT version()`. And what's the current status of `pg_catalog`'s permissions?  Look at `\dp pg_catalog.*` (no need to paste it, but if you see any entries that mention any user except `postgres` paste those). Paste output of `\dn+ pg_catalog`. Comment here after editing your question so I'm notified.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to explain *why* you're trying to do this; sometimes there's a different approach that'll work out better.

Comment: "Didn't work" means the account maintained access to the table using the "Select" statement in a psql environment. Interestingly enough, "\dp pg_catalog.*" gets "permissions denied...". However I can run the query run a select on pg_databases successfully. Running "\dn +pg_catalog" also returns "permission denied". My goal is to revoke permissions from querying or modifying these tables by any other account. Basically protecting the tables from SQL Injection and prying eyes. Running 9.1.10.

Comment: Update:
Using the ideas you gave me, I queried information_schema.table_privileges to find out what roles had permissions to pg_database.
  -- Did not remove permissions from user
  REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_database FROM PUBLIC;

  -- Removed permissions from user
  REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_database FROM PUBLIC;
For whatever reason the schema will NOT let me revoke permissions from the entire schema, if I'm using the "SELECT" statement. However if I REVOKE permissions from a specific table, permissions to the "SELECT" statement for that table are denied as intended.

Answer (score 17):

let me help you about this:

- **1st**: because the `pg_catalog` is owned by the superuser **postgres**, so make sure you login to the server with this role:
  [pg_catalog schema permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsWQF.png)
- **2nd**: make sure you connect to the **right** database that needs to **GRANT/REVOKE** permissions on. GRANT/REVOKE only affect to the **current** database that you connected to. That means after you login with superuser account, issue: **\c [the db]** to connect to that database, the shell will change to: **[the db]=>**
- **3rd**: tables in `pg_catalog` defaults granted SELECT to PUBLIC: [tables in pg_catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvvha.png). So, you have to run REVOKE SELECT FROM PUBLIC and then GRANT SELECT to appropriate users:

  REVOKE SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM PUBLIC;

  GRANT SELECT ON TABLE [table] TO [user];

  For list tables in a database: **pg_class** and **pg_namespace**.

And that's all :)

Answer (score 7):

What you are trying to accomplish is denied in PostgreSQL by design.

If a user could not access `pg_catalog` schema (as you try to do with `REVOKE` commands), he/she would not be able to run even simplest SELECT query - planner would have no access to table definitions.

Your goal *might* be achieved by `REVOKE`'ing access to all schemas - hence locking user only in his private schema (with `CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION username`).

If any rights are already `GRANT`'ed to `public`, you cannot block them selectively for one user - you can only `REVOKE ... FROM public`.

Relevant documentation:

- [Creating a Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CREATE)
- [Schemas and Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PRIV)