# Row-level-security not working for Postgres internal tables

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, row-level-security

I wanted a work-around for the [PostgreSQL limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070648/restrict-user-to-one-schema-in-postgresql#:%7E:text=It%20is%20impossible,database%20per%20user.) (Hide unrelated schema/tables structure for a user).

I decided to go with the Row-Level-Security(RLS). The RLS seems working as expected for the user tables but did work for the internal tables such as `pg_catalog.pg_namespace`.

[image: pg_namespace table data before RLS.]

The screenshot shows the original data in the pg_catalog.pg_namespace table without RLS enbled.

```sql
--logged-in as a SUPERUSER(postgres)

SET allow_system_table_mods=on;
ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pgnamespace ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pg_namespace FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

REVOKE ALL ON TABLE pg_catalog.pg_namespace FROM public, utkarsh;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE pg_catalog.pg_namespace TO utkarsh;

CREATE POLICY ensure_right_table ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace 
FOR ALL
USING ((pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspacl::text = '{postgres=UC/postgres,utkarsh=UC/postgres}'));
--nspacl is not an unique column.

SET ROLE utkarsh;

SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
--I can still see all the rows
```

[image: RLS enabled pg_namespace data.]

Comment: Try to _connect_  as `utkarsh` instead of using `SET ROLE`

Comment: No, this didn't work.

Comment: I doubt you can mess with the system tables like that.