# How to revoke column privileges

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges, sql-revoke

I want to revoke all column privileges.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.column_privileges where grantee='PUBLIC' and privilege_type='UPDATE';
```

I want to return empty of above sql.

I tried to revoke all table and database from postgres and public users,but nothing change.
Like these sql commands;

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM postgres;

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM public;

revoke all privileges on table information_schema from public;

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "db_name" FROM public;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Revoking Permissions from pg\_catalog tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554771/postgresql-revoking-permissions-from-pg-catalog-tables)

Comment: Be more specific. Show a specific case where you meet the problem. Then maybe somebody can find out where you are going wrong.