# Prevent AWS Postgres Read Only User From Seeing Other Objects

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to limit the ability of a read only user in postgres to only a certain view.  I want to prevent them from seeing other schemas / tables / columns that they don't have permission to.

I tried this:
[PostgreSQL Revoking Permissions from pg_catalog tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554771/postgresql-revoking-permissions-from-pg-catalog-tables)

This worked on my local test database but not on my AWS database because apparently AWS locks down permissions to many tables in the pg_catalog schema and if I try to revoke select on those tables I get

ERROR:  permission denied for relation

Is there a way in an AWS deployed postgres (10.6) database to limit what a read only user can see?