# Access a PostgreSQL table without directly using its name

Tags: postgresql, security, row-level-security

**Problem**
I want to prevent a database user from discovering other tables through the use of queries like `select * from pg_tables;` by adding sanitization in the application that executes the query.

I'm busy investigating how to limit access to a PostgreSQL database for queries coming through an application layer where I can still sanitize a query with code. The user does not connect straight to the database. They can execute queries through an application layer (e.g. query is passed through as text and then executed by my application).

I've already enabled Row Security Policies (row level security) and the user is accessing their data through a view, so "access to data" has been solved (I believe). The problem I'm trying to solve now is to prevent them from "seeing" other tables in the database, especially the built-in PG tables.

The only grant the user has is `grant select on my_view to my_user_role;`

**Assumption / attempted solution**
My assumption is that a user can't access a table without explicitly writing it into the query, so if I were to look for certain keywords in the query string, I can reject a query without executing it. E.g. if the clause/characters `"pg_tables"` are anywhere in the query, then I can reject it. *But, this feels naive*.

```js
const query = "select * from pg_tables;";
const flagged = query.includes("pg_tables");
if (flagged) throw Error("Not allowed!");
// Continue to run the user's query
```

^ This would work reliably if the only way to access a table like `pg_tables` is to type that out explicitly.

**Question**
Is there a way to access a table like `pg_tables` without naming it explicitly, in PostgreSQL [given the context above]?

---

*An example of a similar situation in javascript is if you have a function `fooBar()`, then you can access it indirectly by calling `global["foo" + "Bar"]()` – hence not using the text `"fooBar"` exactly.*

Comment: Not tested, but did you read [PostgreSQL Revoking Permissions from pg_catalog tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554771/postgresql-revoking-permissions-from-pg-catalog-tables) ?

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, let me check that out!

Comment: @Luuk, `revoke select on all tables in schema pg_catalog from public;` solves that perfectly. I realise what I missed was that there are certain default grant's on `public` that one has to explicitly revoke, since they can't be overwritten.