# How to restrict access to the pg_catalog tables in AWS RDS PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-administration

I have tried multiple ways to restrict access to the `pg_catalog` system tables in an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance, but I still cannot find a solution.

For example, outside of RDS, the following command revokes access to `pg_catalog.pg_namespace` when run as the `postgres` superuser:

```
revoke select on pg_catalog.pg_namespace from public;
```

But when I run the above command in RDS as the *Master User* (a member of the `rds_superuser` role, and usually called `postgres`), I get the following:

```
WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "pg_namespace"
```

I also get the same warning when I try to revoke access from any other role or user. For example, the following also fails:

```
revoke select on pg_catalog.pg_namespace from any_user;
```

**How do I revoke access to a `pg_catalog` table in RDS?**

Comment: "*restrict access to the `pg_catalog` system tables*" - [which ones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html), why and [are you sure](https://dbfiddle.uk/VMZDW4WT)

Comment: You can refer from this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554771/postgresql-revoking-permissions-from-pg-catalog-tables

Comment: Comments here do not point to solution that work for RDS instances.

Comment: @Diego Comments here do not point to solutions, period.